# I sent bitcoin address to user and he sent payment, I haven't recieved payment after 24hours?

Tags: transactions, payment

I sent bitcoin address to the user and he sent payment, I haven't received payment after 24hours ?

My transactions have been confirmed 120+ times. Here is a link to my transaction:

https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/36d073503d15b22d3877ded86798e50d819ea4f01307cd155806006bab8c7065#i=0

https://explorer.bitcoin.com/btc/tx/36d073503d15b22d3877ded86798e50d819ea4f01307cd155806006bab8c7065

I would like to know if there's a way to recover it back, or at least explain to me why this has happened and how to prevent it later on.

Comment: what wallet are you using?

Answer (score 2):

> My transactions have been confirmed 120+ times

That transaction has been completed and the money received.

Your wallet might not know the money has been received but that is irrelevant so far as the Bitcoin network is concerned.

That transaction sent money to two addresses 1AP3T8gcHiUDdaPYQuBLbRL6Zqg8CF5GGz and 16z1nWRJDcbgDzyQFY62Q37gGHG2duWvKS. One is the payment and the other is change returned to the sender.

If either of these addresses are the address you gave the other person, it means you have received payment. I would check your wallet is fully synchronised and working properly. I would double check that the wallet knows of the address.

If **none** of these addresses are the address you gave the other person, it means this transaction is irrelevant and/or the other person made a mistake, or is not telling the truth.

---

> I would like to know if there's a way to recover it back

As I expect you know, Bitcoin transactions are irreversible. There is no way to cancel, undo or reverse a Bitcoin transaction with more than 120 confirmations.